# How does Solr support REGEX entries for faceted search?

Tags: regex, solr, lucene

I have indexed txt files onto Open Semantic Search and I use regular expressions for the creation of many of my facets. I am trying to create a facet that identifies when a specific term is alone on a single line.

For example:

> "Particular prescription
>
> This sentence is regarding a particular perscription regarding
> protocol for specific nuclear centers. This sentence is regarding
> particular limits regarding protocol for specific nuclear centers.
> This sentence is regarding particular conditions regarding protocol
> for specific nuclear centers."

To be clear, my data is transformed into txt from word files, so their original formatting is all gone.
When the term "Particular prescription" is alone on a line, it means that it and everything below it is a sub-section. I want to create a facet by regex that can simply tell me which documents contain "Particular prescription" alone on a line and not in the sentence as you see in my example text.

Regular expressions used for facets are stored in a tsv file.
Simple regex ideas like ^Particular prescription do not work, so I went into the raw data of the indexed files in Solr...
In this raw data, the text I indexed is this :

> \r\nPrescription particulière\r\nThis sentence is regarding particular
> perscriptions regarding protocol for specific nuclear centers.\r\nThis
> sentence is regarding particular perscriptions regarding protocol for
> specific nuclear centers, \r\n-This sentence is regarding particular
> perscriptions regarding protocol for specific nuclear centers. ,
> \r\n-This sentence is regarding particular perscriptions regarding
> protocol for specific nuclear centers. \r\nThis sentence is regarding
> particular perscriptions regarding protocol for specific nuclear
> centers.\r\nThis sentence is regarding particular perscriptions
> regarding protocol for specific nuclear centers\r\n\r\nThis sentence
> is regarding particular perscriptions regarding protocol for specific
> nuclear centers. \r\n\r\nThis sentence is regarding particular
> perscriptions regarding protocol for specific nuclear centers.\r\nThis
> sentence is regarding particular perscriptions regarding protocol for
> specific nuclear centers.

The correct REGEX I put in my tsv is : (\r\n)+Prescription particulière

*sometimes the term is surrounded by \r\n\r\n

Just to be clear, I tried the double backslash, etc. The regex I'm trying is [\r\n]+Prescription particulière.
I always test my REGEX on a site like RegExr.

Anyways, it does not work and my facet does not appear. I correctly edited the ETL file and all my other REGEX facets work, so it really is a problem of OSS not reading my regex and not linking it to the raw data I find in Solr.

Is there some kind of inconsistency between the data indexed by Solr and OSS' way of visualizing it? Another thing I noticed is that OSS disregards case-sensitivity completely. I tested simply "Prescription" so that it can show me all docs that have "Prescription"(case sensitive, only with the first letter capitalized) and it had "prescription" as a result too! Any ideas how I could add flags or something??? help :)

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what OSS is a reference to, but as far as I remember regular expressions are applied against the generated stored tokens and not the stored text. This means that what they're being applied to is not the complete text you're seeing for the field, but single terms such as "prescription".

Comment: Oh sorry, OSS is Open Semantic Search. Hmm, okay. I'll keep that in mind, thank you